# Best-Practise to migrate data between 2 different SQL Server Schemas?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

### Background

We are currently facing a migration between 2 different SQL Server Schemas.
Both databases use Entity Framework Code-First in the data access layer,
but they are different in terms of structure and data. Following mapping of tables and transformation of data are required. Also different primary keys are a challenge since one database is favoring GUIDs the other database generated integers.

### Current Approach

Currently we are evaluating SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to extract, map and transform the data. In our experience, designing in SSIS can be quiet laborious and confusing.

### 1st Question: Tool

Is SSIS the right tool for the job? 
Should we favor plain SQL or other tools?

### 2nd Question: Process

Are there any processes or best-practise available (i.e. data checking)?
Any course, blog or book recommendations?

Comment: Best tool for what job? It's a *very* good tool for ETL, a lot easier than EF for example and also a lot faster. Not because EF is bad or slow, but because ETL means processing streams of data - something ORMs aren't meant to do. The alternative is using raw SQL statements. This won't be easier though. It's ETL itself that is laborious, not SSIS. Courses, books etc - all courses and books on ETL, data warehousing, SSIS. Pluralsigh has some good courses, which are free through Visual Studio Dev Essentials (also free)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a specific Pluralsight course in mind? Is there a better tool than SSIS?

Comment: You can write the migration SQL scripts. Are you sure what you perceive as SSIS problems, aren't really the difficulty of ETL itself? Eg, would you consider Hadoop/Pig better? No tool is going to automagically split a table vertically to reflect a parent-child relation or clean dirty data without knowing what constitutes clean or dirty.

Comment: We hoped to mitigate problems with foreign key constraints by using the SSIS. We just want to focus on the data itself, not to much on SQL syntax.

Comment: Just wondered if there are different tools, which are more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using SSIS. In the beginning the learning curve was quiet high, but now we are leveraging the benefits concerning transparency and tool support.